# Trunk Port on Dell PowerConnect 5424

Tags: networking

I need to configure a port on a PowerConnect 5424 to function as a Trunk port.  That port will be connected to a Cisco router that will deliver traffic for 2 seperate VLANS - I need the switch to deliver the traffic to the proper VLAN.

From the Web config tool, I am able to configure a port to function in Trunk mode, but I don't see a way to then set the VLANS that I want that port to participate within.  When I set the port to Port VLAN Mode of Trunk, the PVID is set to 1 and I don't see a way to change the PVID or to add multiple values to it as I would expect.

Any insight on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go back to the port VLAN membership screen and select VLANs for that port.  You do it on a port-by-port basis, not VLAN-by-VLAN basis, which is kinda backwards for trunk ports.

Recall that the PVID, or Priority VLAN ID, is the vlan that the switch will assign untagged packets to should that port ever see such packets.  So you want to ensure that this is not set to the VLANs you are expecting to tag through the port.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to do it on the web interface as i turn them off as a matter of course when configuring a switch, but here is the commands to do it on the CLI (it's from  a trunk config between a 5424 and a cisco switch):

```
interface ethernet 1/7
description some_description
no negotiation
switchport allowed vlan add 1 untagged
switchport native vlan 1
switchport mode trunk
switchport allowed vlan add 1,3-10 tagged
```

yes yes, i know using VLAN1 is a no no ... but honestly the dells are such a PITA that getting them to work - well getting them to work at all - with somethings besides vlan 1 just wasn't worth the effort. It'll be changed as soon as I pull the last of them off my network.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful info.  I'm still a newbie at this stuff and prefer the Web console, but good to have the commands to do it also.

Answer (score 0):

here is a CLI solution the top is a general solution, the bottom specifically sets up ports 23 and 24 as trunk ports.

Trunk Ports

console> enable

console# config

console(config)# vlan database

console(config-vlan)# vlan 2    (number as appropriate, repeat for each
VLAN not already created on the switch that needs to be)

console(config-vlan)# exit

console(config)# interface ethernet g24   (use whatever port you like)

console(config-if)# switchport mode trunk

console(config-if)# switchport trunk allowed vlan add 2   (use desired
VLAN number, repeat for each VLAN that needs to be on the trunk, other than VLAN 1.)

console(config-if)# end console# copy run start

======================= Specific ================

enable

config

vlan database

vlan 100

vlan 101

vlan 103

exit

interface ethernet g23

switchport mode trunk

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 100

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 101

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 103

interface ethernet g24

switchport mode trunk

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 100

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 101

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 103

end console# copy run start